# Where clause parentheses in Laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I echo out my query using `dd($query->toSql());`  I get:

```
"select `item_num`, `item_name`, `primary_color`, `content` 
    where (`item_name` NOT LIKE ? and `item_name` NOT LIKE ? and `item_name` NOT LIKE ? ) 
and `primary_color` = ? or `primary_color` = ? or `primary_color` = ? 
order by `item_name` asc ◀"
```

What I need are parantheses around `(`primary_color`= ? or`primary_color`= ? or`primary_color `= ?)` so that the query looks like:

```
"select `item_num`, `item_name`, `primary_color`, `content` 
    where (`item_name` NOT LIKE ? and `item_name` NOT LIKE ? and `item_name` NOT LIKE ? ) 
and (`primary_color` = ? or `primary_color` = ? or `primary_color` = ? )
order by `item_name` asc ◀"
```

Here is my code:

```
$query = DB::table('my_table');
$query = $query->select(array('item_num', 'item_name', 'color', 'content'));
    
$query = $query->where($this->filterArr);

$cc = count($myArr);
$ii = 0;

foreach ($myArr as $key => $value) {
    $myArr = explode(" ", $value);
    if($ii==0)
      $query = $query->where( function(){ $column, '=', $myArr[0]);
    else
      $query = $query->orWhere($column, '=', $myArr[0]);

      if(count($myArr)>1){
        foreach($myArr as $filter){

          if ($key=='collection'){
            $filter = str_replace("-", " ", $filter);
          }

          $query = $query->orWhere($column, '=', $filter);
        }
      }
    }

  $ii++;
}

$query = $query->orderBy('item_name', 'asc')
              ->simplePaginate(50);
```

from this I get an error `syntax error, unexpected ','`   from this line `$query = $query->where( function(){ $column, '=', $myArr[0]);`

Can anyone lend a hand adding parentheses around WHERE statement please.
Thank you.

**edit** `$myArr` is a set of filters

```
  Array (
    [color] => blue
    [color] => purple
    [material] => slick granite
  )
```

Comment: Your code is fairly messy and for us to fix your problem you need to include $myArr and what it is defined as. There must be a better solution that this tbh.

Comment: @mrhn added an example of myArr, yes there are lots of conditions but i couldnt work around all the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, btw your loop looks so messy XD

if this is what you want to achieve
[image: screenshot]
assumed :

```
$myArr = Array (
  "color" => "blue"
  "color" => "purple"
  "material" => "slick granite",
  "collection" => "slick-granite-blue-purple"
);
```

and if array has key name "collection" then replace array value ("-") to (" ")

```
$query = DB::table('your_table');
$query = $query->select(array('item_num', 'item_name', 'color', 'content'));
        
$query = $query->where(function($query){
  $query = $query->where('item_name', '!=', 'item1');
  $query = $query->where('item_name', '!=', 'item2');
  $query = $query->where('item_name', '!=', 'item3');
});//im using !=, replace with your need

$query = $query->where(function($filter) use($myArr){
  $ii=0;
  foreach ($myArr as $key => $value) {
    if($ii==0){
      if($key == 'collection')
        $value = str_replace('-', ' ', $value);
      $filter = $filter->where($key, '=', $value);
    }else{
      if($key == 'collection')
        $value = str_replace('-', ' ', $value);
      $filter = $filter->orWhere($key, '=', $value);
    }
    $ii++;
  };
});
```

Comment: but what about the final `$query = $query->orderBy('item_name', 'asc')->simplePaginate(50); `, where does that fit in?

Comment: yes it is, and I have a better understanding of writing queries now.